# httplib binary data and UnicodeDecodeError in python 2.7

Tags: python, pyamf, httplib2, httplib

I just discovered that starting with Python 2.7, the `httplib` doesn't work anymore with binary data, breaking modules that where sending binary data over HTTP, one example being [PyAMF](http://www.pyamf.org/index.html)

- Python bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue11898
- PyAMF bug: http://dev.pyamf.org/ticket/823

I am looking for a solution to the current bug, preferably one that does not require me to patch Python. Still patching PyAMF seams as an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a [PyAmf version for python 2.7](http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/P/PyAMF/PyAMF-0.6.1.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=0c2c0582fe617b471b2fc81291f38262). other versions can be found [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAMF/).